# storm-kafka KafkaSpout: setting priority among topics

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-storm

Does apache storm `KafkaSpout` have notion of setting priority among source topics that it is subscribing to?

For instance, if `KafkaSpout` is subscribing to topics `t1`, `t2`, `t3` is there a way  to control the consumption rate like `70%` from `t1`, `20%` from `t2` and `10%` from `t3` and if there aren't any messages left in topic `t1` then allocate `t1`'s resources to `t2` and so on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not built in. Kafka doesn't have a concept of topic priority. It's possible to build something like this using the `KafkaConsumer.pause` and `KafkaConsumer.resume` methods. The spout doesn't have support for this right now, but if you'd like to see it added, you can raise an issue at https://issues.apache.org/jira. If you'd like to work on adding it, you can find the Storm code at https://github.com/apache/storm.